# Get value from MessageHeaders in C#

Tags: asp.net-core, wcf, soapcore

I'm using an asp.net 6 application and using [SoapCore](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore).

To get the headers in my service, I created a custom inspector with ***IMessageInspector2*** and pass the headers to my service.

Now, I have all headers in my service but can not read the values.

How can I read the value?

```
    public class MessageFilter : IMessageInspector2
        {
              public MessageFilter (IHttpContextAccessor acc, ILogger<MessageFilter> logger, IMyService myService)
              {
                  _acc = acc;
                  _logger = logger;
                 _myService = myService;
              }
    
              public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message message, ServiceDescription serviceDescription)
              {
                    _myService.SetHeaders(message.Headers);
                    return null;
              }

...
        }
```

Finally in my service when I want to read the value there is an xml tag like:

```
<htng:CorrelationID>[guid]</htng:CorrelationID>
```

The value is xml but I need the value:

```
var value = _messageHeaders[1].ToString();
```

How can I deserialize it to a model? or get the Guid as value?